# Random Prompt showing up when executing code that isn't found in my code anywhere

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am trying to do these steps:
1. Prompt user for three inputs, course_no, depart, and enrollment. 
2. Check if depart is found in my departments table. 
3. If it is found, check for an available room that satisfies condition. If not, print message.

Here is my code:

```
ACCEPT course_no number PROMPT "Enter course_no:  ";
ACCEPT depart PROMPT "Enter Department name: ";
ACCEPT Enrollment number PROMPT "Enter Enrollment: ";

DECLARE
deptFound number;
availableRooms number;
roomNumber  number;

BEGIN
select case
                when exists (select 1 from dept where code = '&depart')
                then 1
                else 0
           end as d_exist
        into deptFound
 from dual;

 if deptFound = 1 then
        select count(*) into availableRooms from rooms where capacity > &enrollment;
        if availableRooms > 0 then
                select room_no into roomNumber from rooms r where capacity  = ( select min(capacity) from rooms where capacity > &enrollmen) and rownum = 1;


        else
                DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('No available rooms!');
        end if;
  end if;


END;
/
```

However, when I run this, it asks me for course_no, department name, and enrollment, then it prompts me  with this:

```
 Enter value for enrollmen:
```

I don't even have that prompt in my code. Where is it coming from??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well you actually do have that in your code. But to see it you need to understand substitution variables. See [PLSQL 101 Substitution vs bind variables](https://community.oracle.com/docs/DOC-915518).  In this particular case that prompt actually exists twice at:

"select count(*) into availableRooms from rooms where capacity > **&enrollment**"

and again at

" ... from rooms where capacity > **&enrollment**  ..."